# Is it possible to make a Custom Library Module aware of Cookbook Attributes in Chef?

Tags: ruby, chef-infra

I have a helper module which aids in working with a database.  The helper module has been created as a custom DSL as per https://docs.chef.io/custom_resources/#custom-resource-dsl.  I use the helper within recipe execution rather than a custom resource.  The helper module has a collection of methods, each of which makes use of common database parameters like so:

```rb
module DatabaseHelper
  def self.execute_query(db_user, db_password, db_name, query)
      #...
  end

  def self.patch_exists(patch_class, db_user, db_password, db_name)
    #...
  end

  def self.remove_data_patch(patch_class, db_user, db_password, db_name)
    #...
  end

  def self.check_structure(db_user, db_password, db_name, code)
    #...
  end
end
```

Seeing the obvious need for DRY here, my thought was to add the db_user, db_password, and db_name values as instance variables like so:

```rb
module DatabaseHelper
  @db_user = node[:magento][:mysql][:db_user]
  @db_password = node[:magento][:mysql][:db_password]
  @db_name = node[:magento][:mysql][:db_name]
#...
```

And now, my problem: these database values are actually chef attributes which are not known by the module.  Is it possible to inform the module about them? I realize I could create a custom resource which would be aware of the attributes, and if that's my only recourse, then so be it.  I'd prefer to use this Module-based approach if I can, though, since most of these methods return booleans used in conditionals or guards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Node object is accessible from library as `Chef.node`.

```rb
module DatabaseHelper
  @db_user = Chef.node[:magento][:mysql][:db_user]
  @db_password = Chef.node[:magento][:mysql][:db_password]
  @db_name = Chef.node[:magento][:mysql][:db_name]
  [...]
end
```

Comment: This statement is accurate and was helpful (thank you).  That said, while I was able to access the attributes via the node object, I was not able to use them as instance variables in a module as is shown in my question and in this answer.  I got around that by defining a method which defines the variables and using that method in other module methods. Chances are that to do this properly, I may need to use a class rather than a module.